# Writing MApreduce code for counting number of records

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I want to write a mapreduce code for counting number of records in given CSV file.I am not getting what to do in map and what to do in reduce how should I go about solving this can anyone suggest something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mapper must emit a fixed key ( just use a Text with the value "count") an a fixed value of 1 (same as you see in the wordcount example).

Then simply use a [LongSumReducer](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/reduce/LongSumReducer.html) as your reducer.

The output of your job will be a record with the  key "count" and the value isthe number of records you are looking for.

You have the option of (dramatically!) improving the performance by using the same LongSumReducer as a combiner.

Comment: thanks for your anwer can you please tell me what exactly is LongSumReducer and how it is different from normal reducer?

Comment: LongSumReducer is a simple implementation of a reducer that does exactly what you need. So you don't have to write it yourself. I added the URL to the documentation in my answer.

Comment: can you please tell me how to use LongSumReducer? can you provide me code snippet which will help me?

Comment: This code is trivial when you simply try to write it yourself. Checkout a Hadoop tutorial ( http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html ) or a good Hadoop book and try to write it yourself. This is not a "other people do my homework" site.

Answer (score 4):

- Your map should emit 1 for each record read
- your combiner should emit the sum of all the "1"s it got (sub total per map)
- you reducer should  emit the the grand total number of records

Answer (score 2):

Hope I have a better solution than the accepted answer.

Instead of emiting 1 for each record, why not we just increment a counter in map() and emit the incremented counter after each map task in cleanup().

The intermediate read writes can be reduced. And reducer need to only aggregate list of few values.

```
public class LineCntMapper extends
  Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

 Text keyEmit = new Text("Total Lines");
 IntWritable valEmit = new IntWritable();
 int partialSum = 0;

 public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) {
  partialSum++;
 }

 public void cleanup(Context context) {
  valEmit.set(partialSum);

   context.write(keyEmit, valEmit);

 }
}
```

You can find full working code [here](http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2015/12/faster-way-to-count-number-of-lines-in.html)

Comment: Elegant and efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use **job.getcounters()** to retrieve the values that you have incremented per record after the completion of the job. If you are using java for writing your mapreduce job then use **enum** for counting mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;

public class LineCount 

{
    public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements
            Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> 

{
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text("Total Lines");

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
            OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output,Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException 
    {
        output.collect(word, one);
    }
}

public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements
        Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values,
            OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {
        int sum = 0;
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            sum += values.next().get();
        }
        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(LineCount.class);

    conf.setJobName("LineCount");
    conf.setNumReduceTasks(5);
    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

    JobClient.runJob(conf);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use the identity Mapper and the identity Reducer.

This is the Mapper.class and Reducer.class. Then just read the `map input records`

You really don't have to do any coding to get this.