# Hadoop reduce individual record counts

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, counter

How to get individual output record count for  each reducer output file when map reduce has multiple reducers?

For now I can get total reducer recorder count using REDUCE_OUTPUT_RECORDS counter. But how to get individual reducer counts? I tried to increment reducer output record count in reducer but I could not get output part file name to write to custom counter.

I looking for count of output records of each reducer... Say in total sort order partitioning I want count of records each reducer is emitting... For example total records are 7.. 2 are from reducer 1 and 5 are from reducer 2, kind of statistics..

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking for number of records each reducer is processing. Each reducer is called once for each key/ The size of the list is the one which you need as per what I understood. Then with programming, you need to emit 1 as output of the map for each record read, and then sum them in result and emit it.

You can also use LongSumReducer class provided in hadoop API. Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248846/writing-mapreduce-code-for-counting-number-of-records) helps for further understanding

Comment: I looking for count of output records of each reducer... Say in total sort order partitioning I want count of records each reducer is emitting... For example total records are 7.. 2 are from reducer 1 and 5 are from reducer 2, kind of statistics..

Comment: Well, reducer is called once for each key in the output of Map. And you will output one key-value pair for each reducer. Not sure, then what exactly is your requirement

Comment: In reduce method generally we will emit a key value pair to output file, I need count of those records..

Comment: So you need the count of key-value pairs in the output? is it

Comment: Yes from each reducer separately

Comment: Sorry to say, you were already using REDUCE_OUTPUT_RECORDS, which does the same thing - giving you the reducer record count. And each reducer gives you one pair in output and that is the equal to the number of keys in the mapper output. So am I missing anything here

Comment: Reduce_output_records gives aggregate of count over multiple reducers.. I need count of reducers each separately

Answer (score 0):

To Answer to my own question below are the steps:

1. make a static variable "count" in reduce method and increment the counter whenever emit a key value from reducer.
2. in cleanup method, create a custom counter and use below method to find the reducer part name.
   getConfiguration().getInt( "mapreduce.task.partition", 0)
   for ex: for reducer output filename part-r-00000 above method returns 0

So using this we can identify different reduce part files counts.

Below is the code:

```
MyReduce extends Reducer<..>{
private static int count = 0;
reduce(..){
<your code>
:
count++;
context.write(..);
}
@Override
cleanup(Context output){
output.getCounter("RecordCounter","Reducer-no-"+output.getConfiguration().getInt("mapreduce.task.partition",
                    0)).increment(count);       
}
```