# Azure Power-shell command to get the Count of records in Azure Data lake file

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-data-lake

I have set of files on Azure Data-lake store folder location. Is there any simple power-shell command to get the count of records in a  file? I would like to do this with out using Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemContent command on the file item as the size of the files in gigabytes. Using this command on big files is giving the below error.

Error:
Get-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItemContent : The remaining data to preview is greater than 1048576 bytes. Please specify a 
length or use the Force parameter to preview the entire file. The length of the file that would have been previewed: 
749319688

Answer (score 0):

Azure data lake operates at the file/folder level. The concept of a record really depends on how an application interprets it. For instance, in one case the file may have CSV line or in another a set of JSON objects. In some cases files contain binary data. Therefore, there is no way at the file system level to get the count of records.

The best way to get this information is to submit a job such as a USQL job in Azure Data Lake Analytics. The script will be really simple: An EXTRACT statement followed by a COUNT aggregation and an OUTPUT statement.

If you prefer Spark or Hadoop here is a StackOverflow question that discusses that: [Finding total number of lines in hdfs distributed file using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079372/finding-total-number-of-lines-in-hdfs-distributed-file-using-command-line)