# How to count lines in a file on hdfs command?

Tags: hadoop

I have a file on HDFS that I want to know how many lines are. (testfile)

In linux, I can do:

```
wc -l <filename>
```

Can I do something similar with "hadoop fs" command? I can print file contents with:

```
hadoop fs -text /user/mklein/testfile
```

How do I know how many lines do I have? I want to avoid copying the file to local filesystem then running the wc command.

Note: My file is compressed using snappy compression, which is why I have to use -text instead of -cat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do it with a `hadoop fs` command. Either you have to write a mapreduce code with the logic explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248846/writing-mapreduce-code-for-counting-number-of-records) or this pig script would help.

```
A = LOAD 'file' using PigStorage() as(...);
B = group A all;
cnt = foreach B generate COUNT(A);
```

Makesure you have the correct extension for your snappy file so that pig could detect and read it.

Comment: this is not really the correct method, the easy method is below

Comment: The easy method will not scale, if you have to deal with big data. Other options: Create an external Hive table with one column and count the rows or use a simple Spark job.

Answer (score 89):

**Total number of files:**
`hadoop fs -ls /path/to/hdfs/* | wc -l`

**Total number of lines:**
`hadoop fs -cat /path/to/hdfs/* | wc -l`

**Total number of lines for a given file:**
`hadoop fs -cat /path/to/hdfs/filename | wc -l`

Comment: I like this answer a lot more that the accepted one.  The accepted one seems like a lot of overhead where this is the perfect answer.  Well done!

Comment: Be aware that this will pull all the data from the hdfs folder to your local machine and do the line count locally. If the amount of data is large, this might be very slow due to bottlenecks in the network IO and memory usage. For large data, a map-reduce/pig approach would be better.

Comment: @ScottH Nice comment, and for very big sets I would worry about IO, but are you sure that memory usage is an issue? From how `hadoop fs -cat something | head` works, I would expect the data to be 'reduced' as you go.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Sounds plausible that it might "reduce" as it goes. I haven't tested that. If you figure out whether memory is actually an issue, I'd be interested in hearing about it.

Comment: Will it need long time when the hdfs path is too large?

Comment: This doesn't report the correct record count if the files are compressed.

Answer (score 6):

**1. Number of lines of a mapper output file:**

```
`~]$ hadoop fs -cat /user/cloudera/output/part-m-00000 | wc -l`
```

**2. Number of lines of a text or any other file on hdfs:**

```
`~]$ hadoop fs -cat /user/cloudera/output/abc.txt | wc -l`
```

**3. Top (Header) 5 lines of a text or any other file on hdfs:**

```
`~]$ hadoop fs -cat /user/cloudera/output/abc.txt | head -5`
```

**4. Bottom 10 lines of a text or any other file on hdfs:**

```
`~]$ hadoop fs -cat /user/cloudera/output/abc.txt | tail -10`
```